# How to determine whether any two categories of a collection of categories are equivalent

Tags: category-theory

Suppose that we have a collection $\textbf{C}$ of categories. Is there a 'systematic' way to determine whether any two categories $C$ and $D$ in $\textbf{C}$ are equivalent, i.e. whether there are functors $F:C\rightarrow D$ and $G:D\rightarrow C$ such that $FG$ is naturally isomorphic to $Id_D$ and $GF$ is naturally isomorphic to $Id_C$, where $Id_C$ and $Id_D$ are the identity functors on $C$ and $D$ respectively.

Comment: Seems highly unlikely. It might depend on the nature of $\mathbf C.$

Comment: For example, even if $C$ and $D$ have one object, you are asking whether two monoids are isomorphic.